# Can't send an .exe file over flask

Tags: python, flask

When I am trying to send a .exe file using send_file() function of Flask (python 2.7) I get this error

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 
'C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\mom\x08uild\\s6\\s6.exe'
```

where `s6.exe` is my file I want to send

Comment: Can you post your code that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `\x08` in `mom\x08uild` is a backspace. That's probably not what you intended: backspaces are not valid in normal Windows filenames, hence the 'invalid filename' error.

It's a bit hard to know for sure without seeing the code, but you might have forgotten to escape a back*slash* somewhere, causing a `\b` to appear (which also means backspace).